# Deserilized Json String to Multiple outputs

Tags: c#, json, ssis, system.web.extensions

I am trying to return the values in my De serialized JSON response to different outputs but when i go to output them I only see the RootObject attributes.

In the SSIS Script Component I have created the following outputs
[image: SSIS Script Component Outputs]

I have declared the following classes.

```
public class Application
{
    public int App_ID { get; set; }
    public string App_Ref { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Error_Code { get; set; }
    public string Error_Message { get; set; }
    public string Create_Dt { get; set; }
    public string Modify_Dt { get; set; }
    public string Client_Name { get; set; }
    public string Client_Code { get; set; }
    public string Centrelink_Status { get; set; }

}
public class Response
{
    public List<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public string Current_Dt { get; set; }
    public string Last_App_Dt { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public Response Response { get; set; }

}
```

My raw Json Response looks like this.

```
{
  "Success": true,
  "Response": {
    "Applications": [
      {
        "App_ID": 1638486,
        "App_Ref": "Test Example",
        "Status": "Complete",
        "Error_Code": null,
        "Error_Message": null,
        "Create_Dt": "2014-05-14 03:09:01.030 +00:00",
        "Modify_Dt": "2014-05-14 03:10:59.757 +00:00",
        "Client_Name": "Silver Chef",
        "Client_Code": "SLVC01",
        "Centrelink_Status": "Receiving_Logons"
      },
      {
        "App_ID": 1637906,
        "App_Ref": "SME Demo",
        "Status": "Complete",
        "Error_Code": null,
        "Error_Message": null,
        "Create_Dt": "2015-10-08 03:07:26.793 +00:00",
        "Modify_Dt": "2015-10-08 03:23:32.833 +00:00",
        "Client_Name": "Silver Chef",
        "Client_Code": "SLVC01",
        "Centrelink_Status": "Receiving_Logons"
      },
      {
        "App_ID": 1585286,
        "App_Ref": "Test",
        "Status": "Receiving_Logons",
        "Error_Code": null,
        "Error_Message": null,
        "Create_Dt": "2015-12-04 03:12:49.617 +00:00",
        "Modify_Dt": "2015-12-04 03:12:49.617 +00:00",
        "Client_Name": "Silver Chef",
        "Client_Code": "SLVC01",
        "Centrelink_Status": "Receiving_Logons"
      },
      {
        "App_ID": 1585398,
        "App_Ref": "Test",
        "Status": "Receiving_Logons",
        "Error_Code": null,
        "Error_Message": null,
        "Create_Dt": "2015-12-04 03:27:59.023 +00:00",
        "Modify_Dt": "2015-12-04 03:27:59.023 +00:00",
        "Client_Name": "Silver Chef",
        "Client_Code": "SLVC01",
        "Centrelink_Status": "Receiving_Logons"
      },
      {
        "App_ID": 1585400,
        "App_Ref": "Test",
        "Status": "Receiving_Logons",
        "Error_Code": null,
        "Error_Message": null,
        "Create_Dt": "2015-12-04 03:28:22.903 +00:00",
        "Modify_Dt": "2015-12-04 03:28:22.903 +00:00",
        "Client_Name": "Silver Chef",
        "Client_Code": "SLVC01",
        "Centrelink_Status": "Receiving_Logons"
      }
],
    "Current_Dt": "2016-11-11 01:01:01.743 +00:00",
    "Last_App_Dt": "2016-10-03 22:48:56.397 +00:00",
    "Count": 500,
    "Total": 1870
  }
}
```

The method is have used to send and receive the response is this and it seems to be de-serializing without error. and i can output "Success" attribute.

```
private RootObject GetWebServiceResult(string vAPIUrl)
    {

        string vAPIToken = Variables.APIToken;

        //Create Web Request
        HttpWebRequest apireq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(vAPIUrl);
        apireq.ContentType = "application/json";
        apireq.Method = "POST";

        string jsonPostStr = "{\"Settings\": {\"API_Token\": \"" + vAPIToken + "\"}, \"Payload\": {}}";
        byte[] postString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonPostStr);

        apireq.ContentLength = postString.Length;

        Stream jsonStream = apireq.GetRequestStream();

        jsonStream.Write(postString, 0, postString.Length);
        jsonStream.Close();

        // Get Web Response        
        HttpWebResponse apirsp = (HttpWebResponse)apireq.GetResponse();
        RootObject jsonResponse = null;

        Stream jsonRspStream = apirsp.GetResponseStream();
        string apiResponseString = null;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonRspStream)) 
        {
            apiResponseString = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
            Console.WriteLine(apiResponseString);
            reader.Close();
        }


        JavaScriptSerializer returnJson = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        //var serialJsonStr = returnJson.Serialize(apiResponseString);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(apiResponseString);

        jsonResponse = returnJson.Deserialize<RootObject>(apiResponseString);

        return jsonResponse;

    }
```

However when I try and write to the Applications output buffer to return i only see Success and Response. (cant output response to string either, but think this is because it is longer than 8000 characters)

When i try and set the values for each application I see this. [image: setting output values]

and i get the following error on my foreach statement.

> "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'ScriptMain.Response' because 'ScriptMain.Response' does not contain a
>   public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Please help! This is driving me insane! What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your `Response` object is not a `List` to enumerate. You need to go `outPutResponse.Response.Applications` if you are looking to loop `Application` object. Else everything else looks good.

Comment: Please add only the necessary/relevant section of code

Comment: Rahul, I think everything i posted as relevent to the error i was getting.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to iterate over is `Response.Applications`:

```
foreach (Application app in outPutResponse.Response.Applications)
{
    ApplicationBuffer.AddRow();
    ApplicationBuffer.AppID = app.App_ID;
}
```

Comment: I am able to output the "Success" bool from the Response but I am unable to get back anything else from the response as I am getting a **_"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."_** error when I try and do the following.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look on the

```
public class RootObject
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
                    ^
}
```

And another part is since you want all the Application it should be `outPutResponse.response.Applications` in the foreach loop

and lastly

```
ApplicationBuffer.AppID = app.App_ID;
```